# Nginx: Is it possible to get response retuned from auth_request

Tags: authentication, nginx

I am using auth module for nginx. (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html)
Is it possible somehow to store the response from the /auth, so I can send it as a request body to another endpoint.

```
location /private/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    proxy_pass ... 
    proxy_set_body 'Here I want to put /auth response. How?';
}

location = /auth {
    proxy_pass ...
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Short answer:*

No, you can't.

*Long answer:*

You can't get body of a response returned to `auth_request`. You can get a header returned in the response though, using the [auth_request_set](http://nginx.org/r/auth_request_set) directive:

```
location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $auth_foo $upstream_http_foo;
    proxy_pass ...
    proxy_set_body $auth_foo;
}
```

The above configuration will set the `$auth_foo` variable to the value of `Foo` header of an auth subrequest.

Comment: With NGINX JavaScript module's help, it might be done. Check this out: https://github.com/nginxinc/NGINX-Demos/tree/master/oauth2-token-introspection-oss

Comment: @bitmountain How does the example you posted here help with returning the authentication response?